# PHP SQL Connect

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For some reason my SQL won't connect any idea's?
I used functions to connect to the SQl but having some trouble because it tells me the the $row_results gives back no data.

```
function db_connect() {
$db_connect = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
if (!$db_connect)
{
    die('Can not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db($db_name, $db_connect);
}

function db_close() {
    mysql_close($db_connect);
}

function db_select($table_name, $table_where) {
    $row_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM '$table_name' WHERE email='$table_where'");
    $row_get = mysql_fetch_array($row_result);
    $row_count = mysql_num_rows($row_result);
}


db_connect();

db_select("attachments", "email@email.com");
die($row_get['email']);

db_close();
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: The syntax highlighting shows that your script has an error.

Comment: Do not use mqsql_* functions. Use mysqli or PDO. There is a syntax error on `die('Can't connect: ' . mysql_error());` where you need to escape the apostrophe in "Can\'t"

Comment: You need to replace `die('Can't connect: '` with `die("Can't connect: "` for starters...

Answer (score 2):

One problem I can see, is this function:

```
function db_select($table_name, $table_where) {
    $row_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM '$table_name' WHERE email='$table_where'");
    $row_get = mysql_fetch_array($row_result);
    $row_count = mysql_num_rows($row_result);
}
```

You are not returning anything from it.

You could start by using for example:

```
function db_select($table_name, $table_where) {
    $row_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM '$table_name' WHERE email='$table_where'");
    $row_get = mysql_fetch_array($row_result);
    $row_count = mysql_num_rows($row_result);

    return array($row_count, $row_get);
}
```

And you really need to switch to prepared statements with bound variables in PDO or mysql to avoid the sql injection problem you have now.

Comment: Ahh yes, variable scoping. Nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
if (!$db_connect)
{
    die('Can\'t connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: I know that wasn't the problem through I only changed it to can't for stackoverflow.

Comment: Try to print your query and put it directly in sql. do you have any result?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$db_config = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
        /* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

For later versions of PHP its is recommended to use the improved MySQL library.

Answer (score 0):

In this line you have quotes around the table name.

```
$row_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM '$table_name' WHERE email='$table_where'");
```

Do not put quotes around the table name. Running `mysql_error()` after the select will likely spit back an error relating to this.

Also, `mysql_*` are being deprecated. You should be using `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

you've got a problem with your variables.
outside the function `db_select` the variable $row_get does not exist ! 
If you want to send your result in a new variable, yo've got to use return like that :

```
function db_select($table_name, $table_where,$connection) {

    $row_result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($table_where).'");
    $row_get = mysqli_fetch_array($row_result);
    $row_count = mysqil_num_rows($row_result);
    return array($row_get,$row_count);
}


$var = db_select("attachments", "email@email.com", db_connect());
echo $var[0]['email'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Document

## List of Employees

ID First Name Last Name Email Phone Address Action   
 connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error); } 
// read all row from database table $sql = "SELECT * FROM employees"; $result = $connection->query($sql); 
if (!$result) { die("Invalid query: " . $connection->error); } 
// read data of each row while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { echo " " . $row["id"] . " " . $row["first_name"] . " " . $row["last_name"] . " " . $row["email"] . " " . $row["phone"] . " " . $row["address"] . "  Update Delete  "; }

$connection->close(); ?>     this better

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).